# set of objects into array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a set of objects in react like :-

```
[id:1,name:'xyz',address:{pincode:2456,street:'XYZ'}{......}{.........}]
```

and I want this set of objects into array of objects like:-

```
[{id:1,name:'xyz',pincode:2456,street:'xyz'}{.......}{........}]
```

Comment: Your "set" is invalid. Is it supposed to be an object literal? They have curly braces `{}`. And your "array" is invalid as arrays don't have properties like that. It is thus really unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: destruction doesnt make sense here...

Comment: btw, you can not have the same key twice in an object.

Comment: both code examples are not in valid javascript... check syntax for objects and arrays

Answer (score 0):

## Assuming you mean an object

You can get this with the spread operator.

```
const {id, name, product} = {id:1,name:'xyz',product:{id:2,class:'two'}};
const newObject = {id, name, ...product};
```

You basically explode the product inside a new object, that will pull the inside out to the level you want.

### Note

Since the key id already exists in the object it cannot be written again. and the spread out product will overwrite it. giving

`{name:'xyz',id:2,class:'two'}`

Answer (score 0):

By havinf an array of objects with nested objects, you could destructure the nested object and spread it into a new object along with the collected rest of the object.

This approach featues

- [Rest in Object Destructuring `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring) for getting the rest of the object without  destructured properties and
- [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for add all properties to a new object.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, name:'xyz', product: { foo: 2, class:'two' } }],
    result = data.map(({ product, ...o }) => ({ ...o, ...product }));
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Nina can you please explain in brief

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of `recursion` here. That will work no matter how deeply nested the objects are:

```js
var data  = [{id:1,name:'XYZ',age:15,address:{street:'xyz',pincode:23456}}];

var res = {};
var dataObj = data[0];

function recursive(dataObj){
  Object.keys(dataObj).forEach(i=>{
  if(typeof(dataObj[i]) === 'object'){
    recursive(dataObj[i])
  }else{
    res[i] = dataObj[i]
  }
})
}

recursive(dataObj)

console.log([res])
```